# Pig + Cassandra : ERROR 1070

Tags: hadoop, cassandra, apache-pig

I'm using hadoop 1.0.4, cassandra 1.2.2 and pig 0.11.0.

i want to run this script on the grunt:

```
**grunt> rows = LOAD 'cassandra://Keyspace1/Users' USING CassandraStorage() AS (key, columns: bag {T: tuple(name, value)});**
```

but i'm having this error:

```
**2013-03-19 11:15:54,957 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1070: Could not resolve CassandraStorage using imports: [, org.apache.pig.builtin., org.apache.pig.impl.builtin.]**
```

the log file contain :

### Pig Stack Trace

ERROR 1070: Could not resolve CassandraStorage using imports: [, org.apache.pig.builtin., org.apache.pig.impl.builtin.]

Failed to parse: Pig script failed to parse: 
 pig script failed to validate: org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 1070: Could not resolve CassandraStorage using imports: [, org.apache.pig.builtin., org.apache.pig.impl.builtin.]
    at org.apache.pig.parser.QueryParserDriver.parse(QueryParserDriver.java:191)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer$Graph.validateQuery(PigServer.java:1571)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer$Graph.registerQuery(PigServer.java:1544)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.registerQuery(PigServer.java:516)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.processPig(GruntParser.java:991)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.pigscript.parser.PigScriptParser.parse(PigScriptParser.java:412)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:194)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:170)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt.run(Grunt.java:69)
    at org.apache.pig.Main.run(Main.java:538)
    at org.apache.pig.Main.main(Main.java:157)
Caused by: 
 pig script failed to validate: org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 1070: Could not resolve CassandraStorage using imports: [, org.apache.pig.builtin., org.apache.pig.impl.builtin.]
    at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanBuilder.validateFuncSpec(LogicalPlanBuilder.java:1209)
    at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanBuilder.buildFuncSpec(LogicalPlanBuilder.java:1194)
    at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.func_clause(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:4766)
    at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.load_clause(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:3183)
    at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.op_clause(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:1315)
    at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.general_statement(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:799)
    at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.statement(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:517)
    at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.query(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:392)
    at org.apache.pig.parser.QueryParserDriver.parse(QueryParserDriver.java:184)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 1070: Could not resolve CassandraStorage using imports: [, org.apache.pig.builtin., org.apache.pig.impl.builtin.]
    at org.apache.pig.impl.PigContext.resolveClassName(PigContext.java:523)
    at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanBuilder.validateFuncSpec(LogicalPlanBuilder.java:1206)

## ... 18 more

thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Based on the [Pygmalion](https://github.com/jeromatron/pygmalion) project's [documentation](https://github.com/jeromatron/pygmalion/wiki/Getting-Started) and the source of the [pig_cassandra](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/cassandra/trunk/contrib/pig/bin/pig_cassandra) script you can establish the connection between Cassandra and Pig by doing the followings:

```
for jar in $CASSANDRA_HOME/lib/*.jar; do CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:$jar; done;
export PIG_CLASSPATH=$PIG_CLASSPATH:$CLASSPATH;
export PIG_OPTS="$PIG_OPTS -Dudf.import.list=org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.pig";
export PIG_INITIAL_ADDRESS=localhost;
export PIG_RPC_PORT=9160;
export PIG_PARTITIONER=org.apache.cassandra.dht.RandomPartitioner;
pig
```

Also make sure to include the Cassandra jars to the `HADOOP_CLASSPATH` as well (e.g: set it in hadoop-env.sh)

Answer (score 2):

This is definitely a PIG_CLASSPATH problem. You should be running pig_cassandra from the examples/pig/bin directory that came with the cassandra source distribution. this script builds the classpath for you before running pig.

You also need to set the following env variables:

```
export JAVA_HOME=Oracle java 6 dir
export PIG_HOME=pig directory
export PIG_CONF_DIR=hadoop conf directory(needed if running distributed mapreduce)
export PIG_INITIAL_ADDRESS=ip of a cassandra node
export PIG_RPC_PORT=cassandra RPC port (i.e. 9160)
export PIG_PARTITIONER=org.apache.cassandra.dht.RandomPartitioner
```

Note: you must build the cassandra source using ant once before running pig_cassandra.  This will generate some libs in the cassandra_source/build/lib/jars folder which the pig_cassandra script needs. otherwise, you will get errors starting pig. Can't remember what exactly the error was. It was something along the lines of a method not found during serialization/deserialization stage inside pig.

Answer (score 0):

mine was solved by doing this

```
register hdfs:/udf/cassandra-all.jar;
define CqlStorage org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.pig.CqlNativeStorage();
```